# I just launched flutter app on a physical device yesterday, and now I am getting this issue. Any solutions?

Tags: flutter

I have been running flutter in emulator and just launched it on a physical device yesterday, and now, I am getting this issue. I can neither launch emulator nor physical device now. I have tried many things, and have flutter SDK components installed. My android studio is the latest version. I am a beginner to flutter, would be a great help if you could help.[HERE IS THE IMAGE:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNjjJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried using a different emulator?

Comment: Open any emulator and try flutter run command

Comment: @ Gülsen Keskin and @ Mahi, I appreciate your help. I just had to cold boot the emulator, and everything turned out fine.